# Not saving empty array items into database

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, null

I have a metabox with a dynamic number of fields. If a user has, say, 3 fields, and #1 and #3 are filled in, I want this to not save an empty value for #2. This is saving empty items (... [2] => [3] => foo [4] ...) in an array. How can I keep this from saving these empty values for the fields that a user doesn't fill in?

```
    $mydata = array();
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $data) {
                    if ($key == 'mytheme_meta_box_nonce')
                            continue;

                    if(preg_match('/^nivo/i', $key)) {

                                    $mydata[$key] = $data;
                    }
            }
                    update_post_meta($post_id, slideshow, $mydata);
    return $mydata;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using emtpy() like this:

```
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $data) {
     if ($key == 'mytheme_meta_box_nonce') {
         continue;
     }

     if(!empty($data) && preg_match('/^nivo/i', $key)) {
         $mydata[$key] = $data;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a check to make sure $data contains something:

```
if ((preg_match('/^nivo/i', $key)) &&
    (!empty($data))) {
```

---

This code has nothing to do with OP, demonstrating code spawned from comment conversation.

```
$strlen = strlen('');

var_dump($strlen); // Echos int(0)
var_dump($strlen === false);  // Echos false
var_dump($strlen === 0); // Echos true
var_dump((bool) $strlen === false); // Echos true
```

PHP is a loosely typed language, so the appearance of a false being returned from strlen is misleading.

Comment: Why check against > 0 for the result of !empty()? Isn't it needless?

Comment: Hikaru, your right. I at first used a strlen($data) > 0 check, but backed it out in favor of empty, forgot to remove the >0. Thanks.

Comment: Even when using strlen() it would be needless since 0 will cast to false ;)

Comment: INT 0 casts to false if boolean is needed ;) An empty string will also cast to false and also null will do. So if(strlen($data) ...) will also work the same way.

Comment: I never said it's going to be false - Just wanted to point out it casts to false so the explict check is needless in this situation ;)

Comment: You mentioned that it would cast to false, I just wanted to show you that it doesn't actually cast to false, it's still an int, but PHP will treat a return of 0 as a false if strict data type checking isn't in place. I am a stickler for datatypes so I always do the > 0 in my strlen checks.